# flutter getx video player

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-video-player

i facing an issue where the old video appears briefly before the new video is initialized. This is likely due to the asynchronous nature of loading videos and the time it takes to initialize a new video player in flutter getx.
[image]